# Add vector weighted edges with networkx

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx, weighted

I am facing a problem for which I cannot find a solution. I need to work with a graph data structure, more precisely a weighted oriented graph.
But I wish for the weights, I wish not to add a float but a vector (for example an array numpy)

For example :

```py
import networkx as nx

Graph = nx.DiGraph()

Graph.add_edge("Alpha", "Beta", weight=0.3)
Graph.add_edge("Beta", "Alpha", weight=0.9)
Graph.add_edge("Alpha", "Omega", weight=0.4)

A = nx.to_numpy_array(Graph)

print(A.shape)
```

It's work, ok, and I have (3,3) shape, because I have 3 vertices, ok.
But, I want this :

```py
Graph = nx.DiGraph()

Graph.add_edge("Alpha", "Beta", weight=np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]))
Graph.add_edge("Beta", "Alpha", weight=np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]))
Graph.add_edge("Alpha", "Omega", weight=np.array([0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]))

A = nx.to_numpy_array(Graph)

print(A.shape)
```

I need a (3,3,5) tensor, I need "to weight" each edge by a vector of 5 values.
And I have this error :
"ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,5) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)"

Does anyone have a solution please?

Comment: The weight attribute probably expects a single value instead of an object and fails in casting the array meaningfully into an acceptable value here. Is it an option to take the dot product of the vector or is each value individually meaningful here? One rough workaround for the latter might be to create a MultiDiGraph with a different edge attribute for each of the weight types if that fits your use case (though this would multiply the number of edges overall to the weight vector length so in most cases is probably not what you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally I decided to implement a graph structure in pure python with a class (and with some numpy)